# Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region between the $ x \mbox{ axis}$ and the parabola $y = 4x − x^{2}$ about the line $y = 6$.

Tags: integration

Can anyone help? I've tried disc and shell method but the disc seems the most likely. What I can't seem to do is specify everything correctly.

Comment: Hi Ian. In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the How to Ask-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution.

Comment: See http://curvebank.calstatela.edu/volrev/volrev.htm for help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

- Sketch the line $y=6$ and the region, $R$. Note that $R$ is a "half
  disc" shape in the first quadrant whose "diameter" (flat side) coincides with the
  interval $[0,4]$ on the $x$-axis.
- Imagine what the solid looks like. You are revolving $R$ about the line
  $y=6$. This will generate a donut shape centered about the line
  $y=6$.
- Indeed the disc method is appropriate. Now select an $x\in [0,4]$
  and draw the vertical line segment in $R$ corresponding to $x$. Call
  this line segment $L_x$.
- What shape do you get when $L_x$ is revolved about the line $y=6$? 

  Answer: a disc, $D_x$, of outer radius $6$ and inner radius $6-(4x-x^2)$. So
  the area of $D_x$ is $$\text{area}(D_x)=\pi\bigl(6^2- (6-(4x-x^2) )^2 \bigr).$$
- Finally, use the formula: $$\text{Volume}=\int_0^4
     \text{area}(D_x)\,dx
     =\int_0^4 \pi\bigl( 6^2-(6-(4x-x^2) )^2 \bigr)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thank you David, the explanation is excellent. I understand why the inner radius is 6, but my reckoning says the outer radius would be 6+(4x-x^2). What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: @Ian Sorry; I was off. The disc is in the first quadrant. The outer radius is $6$ and the inner radius is $6-(4x-x^2)$. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I get it now. Your help has moved on my understanding of finding volumes with integrals a few more steps. Thank you.

Comment: @Ian You're welcome.